# Raspberry Pi: "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up a raspberry pi which measures the temperature and humidity in my room via a DHT22 sensor. I found a tutorial on youtube where the scripts and everything else is uploaded, but the python script won't work... I am new to python and I really don't know what to do now. I already searched for a solution, especially here on stackoverflow, but I didn't find anything working for me.

The error message looks like this:

```
python Temperature_Server_DHT.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Temperature_Server_DHT.py", line 49, in <module>
    SensorInforations = sensorCheckIfRegistered(Device_ID)
  File "Temperature_Server_DHT.py", line 37, in sensorCheckIfRegistered
    SensorData = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

And my python script contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# import sys module
import sys
import json
import urllib
import time
import socket
import Adafruit_DHT

#Conf
BaseURL= "http://127.0.0.1/php/Backend.php"
NameSensor= "DHT22"
#

sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
ip = [l for l in ([ip for ip in     socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] if not ip.startswith("127.")]    [:1], [[(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in     [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)$
hostname = socket.gethostname()

def insertTempdata(TSensor_ID, Temperature, Humidity):
    urllib.urlopen(BaseURL + "?Call=AddTempData&TSensor_ID=" + "\"" +     TSensor_ID + "\"" + "&Temperature="+ Temperature + "&Humidity=" + Humidity)

def deviceCheckIfRegistered(IP, Hostname):
        DeviceID = urllib.urlopen(BaseURL + "?Call=getDeviceID&IP=" + IP +     "&Hostname=" + Hostname ).read()
        print (DeviceID)
        if(DeviceID != "null"):
            return DeviceID
        else:
            return ""

def sensorCheckIfRegistered(DeviceID):
        url= BaseURL + "?Call=getRegisteredTSensors&Device_ID=" + DeviceID
        data =  urllib.urlopen(url).read()
        print (data)
        if(data != "null"):
            SensorData = json.loads(data)
            return SensorData
        else:
            return ""

def readDHTSensors(TSensor_ID, GPIO):
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, GPIO)
    print 'Temperature: {0:0.1f}*C Humidity:     {1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature,humidity)
    insertTempdata(TSensor_ID, str(temperature), str(humidity))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Device_ID = deviceCheckIfRegistered(ip, hostname)
    SensorInforations = sensorCheckIfRegistered(Device_ID)
    if(Device_ID != "" and SensorInforations != ""):
        try:
            while True:
                for element in SensorInforations:
                    if(str(element['Sensor']) == NameSensor):
                        readDHTSensors(element['TSensor_ID'], element['GPIO'])
                time.sleep(1800)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            # quit python script
            print("Killed")
            sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("Device not registered")
        sys.exit(0)
```

I hope that you can finally help me, if you need anything else from me just tell me!

Comment: You are already printing ``data``, please include it in your question.

Comment: That's right, but the shown error message is complete, it won't print the data thing...
Edit: I'm just getting 2 blank rows above the Traceback

Comment: are you actually running the php server?

Comment: I can access the main server I set up via the IP of the raspberry, if this was your question...

Comment: What is returned if you go to the URL manually in a browser. Sounds like you're expecting JSON, but that's not what is being returned.

Comment: When I go to the IP shown in the code I can't access it, because I'm connecting to the Pi via Putty. But I have also tried it with the IP address which I'm using with Putty and it won't work either...

Comment: If you need the content of this "Backend.php" just tell me, I will show it then